# Length of a method in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net-to-c#

How does VB.NET calculate the length of a method? How can I do this in C#?

This my [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) code:

```
Private Function ZeroPad(ByRef pNumber As Integer, ByRef pLength As Integer) As String
    Dim Padding As Object
    If IsNumeric(pNumber) And IsNumeric(pLength) Then
        Padding = New String("0", pLength)
        ZeroPad = Padding & CStr(pNumber)
        ZeroPad = Right(ZeroPad, pLength)
    Else
        ZeroPad = CStr(pNumber)
    End If
End Function
```

I converted into C# as follows:

```
private string ZeroPad(ref int pNumber, ref int pLength) {
    object Padding;
    if ((IsNumeric(pNumber) && IsNumeric(pLength))) {
        Padding = new string("0", pLength);
        return (Padding + pNumber.ToString());

        ZeroPad = ZeroPad.Substring((ZeroPad.Length - pLength));

        // In the above line, how can I take the length of a method in C#?
    }
    else {
        return pNumber.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't return values like that in C#. It's also not clear why you're taking the values by reference. I would strongly suggest that you start learning C# from scratch, rather than trying to convert methods without really knowing the language.

Comment: How about [MSDN Padding Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.71).aspx)? The link contains both VB and C# code for padding strings using Basic String operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably confused between the variable `ZeroPad` and the method `ZeroPad`. It is customary to write variable names with a lower case initial character, e.g. `zeroPad`. To return a value from a method, use `return` in C#. I'm not sure what the purpose is of your `IsNumeric` subroutine or why you take value by reference, but your code in C# would be similar to:

```
private string ZeroPad(ref int pNumber, ref int pLength)
{
    string padding;
    string zeroPad;
    if ((IsNumeric(pNumber) && IsNumeric(pLength)))
    {
        padding = new string('0', pLength);
        zeroPad = (padding + pNumber.ToString());

        zeroPad = zeroPad.Substring((zeroPad.Length - pLength));
    }
    else
    {
        zeroPad = pNumber.ToString();
    }
    return zeroPad;
}
```

As you don't change the values of `pNumber` or `pLength`, you can pass them by value (`ByVal` in Visual Basic). And knowing that both `pNumber` and `pLength` are integers, and therefore always numeric, your method could be shortened to the following:

```
private string ZeroPad(int pNumber, int pLength)
{
    string zeroPad;
    string padding = new string('0', pLength);

    zeroPad = (padding + pNumber.ToString());

    zeroPad = zeroPad.Substring(zeroPad.Length - pLength);

    return zeroPad;
}
```

The .NET Framework's Base Class Libraries have a [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx) method that does exactly what you want if you specify `'0'` as the value for `paddingChar`.

Comment: I thought the sZeroPad would least confuse OP oming from a case insensitive language, but +1 for posting before me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me.This is old project.i don't know what there are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you don't assign to method name. Instead you use a "return" statement. Declare a variable:

```
string retVal;
```

And instead of

```
ZeroPad = some_value;
```

use:

```
retVal = some_value;
```

and at last return retVal:

```
return retVal;
```

Comment: use this approach to rewrite your c# code and come back if you still have problem.